# How to create 2 vagrant instances in 2 seperate directories be on the same private network

Tags: python, vagrant, virtualbox

The name of this post pretty much sums my question up. How do I create 2 vagrant instances in 2 seperate directories be on the same private network?

example:

```
app/
   Vagrantfile -> has a single vm instance running
some_other_app/
   Vagrantfile -> also has a single vm instance running
```

Now I want to put them on the same private network. I know that I should put the vms in one folder and it will wire them up for me, but I have a very confusingly written work project that has this structure. In order to test my dev changes I need the machines to be able to speak to eachother on the private network.

Remember:
 - I can not reformat the directory

There certainly has to be a VBoxManage command out there that does this for you.

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Answer (score 1):

Add below to your app Vagrantfile

```
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.100"
```

Then below to your other app Vagrantfile

```
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.101"
```

This will assign them IP in same network and then can reach each other using the IP `192.168.33.100` and `192.168.33.101`

Comment: Yeah but they still don't create a private network between them. I know that what you wrote works if the boxes live and are configured in the same directory.

Comment: No, that is not the case. They can be any directory and different vagrantfiles. As long as they run on same machine it would work

Comment: See this picture. https://i.stack.imgur.com/85JYD.png. I have a VM which has 102 and 103 IP, and it can access VM with 100 IP which is in separate folder

Comment: I will have to test it.